# Samsung LED monitor SyncMaster SA300 horizontal dark lines

Tags: display, led

When I started a video game, suddenly all over the screen appeared a lot of horizontal, dark lines. At first I thought it was graphic card problem, but I've changed monitor and everything looked fine.
Here is a picture of the monitor, with VGA cable unplugged. The "square" that is visible is a signal warning. I have also included a video.
What could cause this problem? Can it be fixed?
Thanks

[image: samsung monitor image]

[samsung monitor video](https://youtu.be/pdBQg-cAX2M)

Comment: How comfortable are you with the idea of opening up your display?

Comment: Very comfortable.

Comment: Well, the simplest thing I can think of is a damaged or loose LVDS cable. Could pop the cover and see if you can remove and replace that to see if it helps

Comment: I unplugged it, then plugged it again. No change.